# Jquery datatable date format "DD/MM/YYYY" not correct ordering with these formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datatable

Jquery datatable column Date format is DD/MM/YYYY not Correctly ordering asc or desc with these date's 27/12/2017 , 18/1/2018 and 15/1/2018.
I google a lot but not found any helpful solutions
Please give me helpful soluation
here is html code.

```
<table id="Tradingdttable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="text-align: start;">Date</th>
            <th style="text-align: start;">Description</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="TradingAccounttbody">

            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:start">27/12/2017</td>
                <td style="text-align:start">2 Kit Light Gray M-1</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:start">18/1/2018</td>
                <td style="text-align:start">Cheque Online Paymet HBL (#) Lahore</td>

            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td style="text-align:start">15/1/2018</td>
                <td style="text-align:start">Cheque Online (#) Gujranwala</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

*Script*

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {

        $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD-MM-YYYY');

        jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
            "date-uk-pre": function (a) {
                var ukDatea = a.split('/');
                return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
            },

            "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
            },

            "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
            }
        });

        $('#Tradingdttable').DataTable({
            "aoColumns": [{ "sType": "date-uk" }, null, null, null, null],
        });

    });
```

Comment: I believe you need to try this as follows:
      $.fn.dataTable.moment().format('('DD-MM-YYYY')');

Comment: thanks for your answer but it giving me an error saying Cannot read property 'format'

Comment: Since you're converting the date strings to numbers, the sort function can be just `function (a, b){return a - b}`. You don't even need to convert to numbers but it might help readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

For more help see, https://momentjs.com/

**EDITED:** make sure you have the https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment plugin imported in your scripts.